# Angular ui-router url parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

When user arrive to following URL

```
mainurl/exampleurl?token=23
```

i can extract the "exampleurl" using this `$state.$current.name`

How can i exctract the `token=23` from this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option-1:** You can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service.

```
 var t = $location.search().token
```

**Option-2** If you are using  `ui-router`, you may access the querystring parameters from [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) service too

```
var t = $stateParams.token
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can get parameters from $stateParams:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

```
var token = $stateParams.token
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try passing $location to your controller and use it like this.

```
.controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location' , function ($scope, $stateParams, $location) {
// Get token from query string
var token = $location.search().token;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameters with [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) into your controller. See below

```
// Given URL
// mainurl/exampleurl?token=23

var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {token: 23}
```